# new git branch from existing one without merging with master

Tags: git, git-branch

I have branch `one` (not merged yet with master) I want to have branch `two` which has everything like in `one`.

Will be `git checkout -b two` enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you are on branch `one`, just execute that command, and branch `two` will be created based at the last commit on branch `one`.